# CSS: Overlaying text over Unslider

Tags: jquery, html, css

I made a very simple Unslider setup with 3 images, I try to overlay a h1 text over it, but when I do, a strange horizontal space appears in my div above the slider ([See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sJdg.png))

Here's my code:

```
<div class="photos" id="photos">
    <h1 class="photos-title">P H O T O G R A P H Y</h1>
    <div class="my-slider">
      <ul>
        <li><img src="images/image1.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="images/image2.jpg" alt=""></li>
        <li><img src="images/image4.jpg" alt=""></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And my CSS:

```
.photos{
  width: 100%; height: 100vh;
}
.my-slider{
  width: 100%; height: 100vh;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
.photos-title{
  font-family: "Anton";
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0,-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This space is the place reserved for the title,
use `position:absolute`

```
.photos-title {
     position: absolute; 
}
.photos{
     position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Please do not ignore my answer (

Comment: i was be first(((